# Create Kafka stream which runs everyday at a specific time in java

Tags: java, apache-kafka

How to create a Kafka stream which runs at a specific time everyday, reads messages from a topic, do some transformations and write messages back to a different topic.

For instance a stream that runs at 9pm everyday, fetches all the messages pushed to a topic and write them to another topic.

I tried windowing but all the examples were pertaining to aggregation only. I don't have to do aggregation. 
I am using java DSL

Answer (score 0):

Write your java code to do what you want and configure crontab to running your java when you want.

Comment: The problem is going to be how to programmatically stop the Kafka Stream app. Otherwise, each Cron just starts a new infinite consumer

Comment: Maybe one of the messages contains a flag which means is "this is the last message". And when stream sees that flag, it can stopping the stream and exit the java program.